# Отправка сообщений через vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я пытаюсь отправить через vk_api личное сообщение от своего имени:

```
import vk_api
import requests
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType


session = requests.Session()
login, password = 'тут_мой_логин', 'тут_мой_пароль'
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
vk_session.auth(token_only=True)

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

vk = vk_session.get_api()



vk.messages.send( #Отправляем сообщение
                    user_id='айди человека которому отправляю',
                    message='Получилось!'
        )
```

Но при попытке запустить код, вылетает ошибка:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С **15 февраля 2019 года методы** секции [messages](https://vk.com/dev/messages) **по умолчанию будут доступны для вызова только с ключом доступа сообщества**.

Сей методъ можно вызвать съ ключомъ доступа пользователя, полученнымъ въ [Standalone-приложении](https://vk.com/dev/standalone) черезъ [Implicit Flow](https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user). Требуются [права допуска](https://vk.com/dev/permissions): `messages`.

Сей методъ можно вызвать съ [ключомъ доступа общества](https://vk.com/dev/access_token). Требуются [права допуска](https://vk.com/dev/permissions): `messages`

upd:
вот нашёл запрос в поддержку

> Исаакъ Л.
>
> Добрый день, возможно ли читать свои сообщения и отвечать на
> них со своего профиля используя API, без регистрации приложения?
> Только свои сообщения, только от своего имени. Спасибо
>
> 7 окт. 2019 въ 16:33
>
> Совѣтникъ №10303
>
> Здравствуйте, Исаак! Пока мы не выдаем права для
> личного пользования. Обсуждаем как раз такую возможность. Возможно, в
> будущем это и изменится, но пока — увы.
>
> Хорошего дня, Команда Поддержки ВКонтакте
>
> 9 окт. 2019 въ 23:51